# Rundeck Permission Denied - Simple shell script

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, rundeck

Setup Rundeck on ubuntu, but have been going round in circles with permissions.

For some reason rundeck seems unable to do anything outside of the logs directory.

As an example:

I have created a simple test directory /opt/rundeck-tests, which is owned by the rundeck user, and has 770 permissions.

However when i run a simple job: echo test > /opt/rundeck-tests/test.txt I get the error "permission denied".

Same when I try to execute an ssh script.  Let me know if and what further info you need, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, your folder "/opt/rundeck-tests" is owner by user rundeck with permission 770

```
drwxrwx--- 2 rundeck rundeck 4096 Mar 11 16:51 /opt/rundeck-tests/
```

and you are running inline script as rundeck job

```
echo test > /opt/rundeck-tests/test.txt
```

If I understood your scenario correctly, you wouldn't get any permission issue at all. In case if you still gets permission issue, try switching to rundeck user on shell and execute the command

```
su rundeck
echo test > /opt/rundeck-tests/test.txt
```

This will let you know the exact linux error rather rundeck.